# Bring subview to front

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a issue where I want to bring the badge notification view which i add to the `UICollectionViewCell` to the front. I am adding a border to the `UICollectionViewCell` using `cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];`
. But when the border is added it appears on the top of the badge view.

[image]

After adding the border:

[image]

I add the badge view to the cell using, `[self addSubview:self.badge];`
 in the class which subclasses `UICollectionViewCell`

I tried, `[self bringSubviewToFront:self.badge];` and `self.badge.layer.zPosition = 1;` but it didn't help. I found these solutions on similar posts on SO, but I think i am doing something wrong. I would be glad if someone could point that out. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I did a little change according to the suggestions, and did `[self.contentView addSubview:self.badge];` instead of `[self addSubview:self.badge];`. When i debug the view and check all the layers of view, it does show the badge on top of the border, but thats not the case in simulator.

Comment: Its because you are adding badge to the same view in which you are applying border, just add another view in which you apply border not in the main view.

Comment: But bringSubviewToFront should still work in that case, right ?

Comment: Try set `cell.layer.borderWidth `, maybe this can help you with the border.

Comment: With `bringSubviewToFront ` you have to point right view. I think that in this case it should be view of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

As @iphonic said, you cannot achieve these using same view for draw border and contain badge.

Try to set these view hierarchy:

```
Cell
   |- ContentView
      |- Main View (Apply border here)
         |- All you content
      |- Badge
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a specific subview for your custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s border, so when you need to make it appear, then you can easily manage to put the badge to the front.

Programmatically it could be something like this (in your custom `UICollectionViewCell`)

```
UIView* border = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
border.tag = 1001;
border.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
[self addSubview:border];
```

And when you need to add and show the badge upfront

```
[self addSubview:self.badge];
[self bringSubviewToFront:[self viewWithTag:1001]];
[self bringSubviewToFront:self.badge];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate CALayer for the badge. It appears that you're drawing both the badge and border in the same layer, hence the merge of the two images.

Comment: out of pure interest, what happens when you set the backgroundColor of the badgeView as a solid colour?

Comment: the border appears over the badge, I have no idea why that happens since in 'view debugging' the badge is clearly over the border.

Comment: What about if you forcibly use a different CGContext to draw in? Shouldn't be necessary at all, but could help pinpoint what's up